# Expressing a Polynomial as a Sum of Squares Of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $P(\alpha)\ge0$ for all real $\alpha$. Show that there exists polynomials with real coefficients $Q_1(x)^2, Q_2(x)^2,....Q_n(x)^2$ such that
             $P(x) = Q_1(x)^2 + Q_2(x)^2 + ... + Q_n(x)^2$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $P(\alpha)\geqslant 0$ for all $\alpha$, then $\deg P$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $P(x)$ in factorised form over the reals. Note that real roots must all have even multiplicity.

The factors can be collected together as $(x-a)^2$ and as $(x-a)^2 +b^2$ for real $a$ and $b$.

Incorporating the leading coefficient, $P(x)$ is therefore a product of the form 
$$(f_1(x)^2+g_1(x)^2)...(f_k(x)^2+g_k(x)^2)$$
Multiplying out appropriately gives you the required sum of squared polynomials.

Comment: Ah I got it, thanks a lot man